# VBA MsgBox Error 438 (On Error GoTo ErrorHandler)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to create a high-quality ErrorHandler. I get run-time error 438:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Here's code:

```
Sub Function_asdf()
...
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
...
ErrorHandler:
& vbNewLine & "Error" & Err.Number & Err.line & Err.Description
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like that, you're doing nothing. You're trying to start a chain of strings, but this starts with a join operator (`&`) which is not connecting to any "first" part, and even if it was it's neither assigned to a variable nor shown into a dialog box.

Start by showing that into a MsgBox :

```
MsgBox vbNewLine & "Error" & Err.Number & Err.line & Err.Description
```

or assigning it to a variable first:

```
Dim errMsg As String
errMsg = vbNewLine & "Error" & Err.Number & Err.line & Err.Description
```

and then printing it:

```
Debug.Print errMsg
```

or logging it into a cell

```
Range("A1") = errMsg
```

or in a MsgBox

```
MsgBox errMsg
```

... and don't forget to specify on which line you're raising the exception (here it's clear, but it's not always evident) cause it would be impossible for someone to debug without knowing in which point of your code the exception is thrown.

### EDIT - I've finally run your code

So, I've run your code and the error is raised because the object `Err` (i.e. the exception thrown) does not have the property `Line`. It might have been deprecated, or just never existed.

If you wanted to return the line on which the error occurs, use the `ERL` property:

```
MsgBox vbNewLine & "Error" & Err.Number & Erl & Err.Description
```

Comment: What would that code look like as a whole? It doesn't fix the syntax. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!        Thanks!

Comment: BE CAREFUL when using this. Erl() will always return 0 if you do not purposefully line your code yourself manually or with an excel add-in. There is no line count in excel VBE like there is in VB.Net used on Visual Studio, for example.